# Use Backbone pushStat without mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, backbone.js, pushstate

On backbone, I know that pushState remove the # from URL.
For a particular reason, I don't want to activate the mod_rewrite in my server side.
So, is it possible and best idea to use pushState without enable this module?
Thanks.

Comment: Salut Léon ,it's possible but totally not reasonable to do this.Basically you'd have to generate a path with an index page for every route possible in your application.And in each index you'd have to put your backbone app! so it's definetly NOT reasonable.

Comment: Salut Mpm! Thank you for your reply :)